# hdparm: What does -n do without a parameter?

Tags: linux, hdparm

The full command I executed in a live CD:

> sudo hdparm -n /dev/sda

What would be the effect of running the command without a parameter? Did the command change anything?

The hdparm [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm) says, about this option ('-n'):

> ```
> Get or set the "ignore write errors" flag in the driver. Do NOT play with this without grokking the driver source code first.
> ```

It says it changes the "ignore write errors" flag in the '**driver**'. Thus, would changes get reset on a reboot or does it affect the drive directly?

The program returned:

> /dev/sda: HDIO_GET_NOWERR failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device.

What does this mean?

[This](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ioctl/hdio.txt) appears like it is related (search: 'HDIO_GET_NOWERR').

[This](https://azrael.digipen.edu/~mmead/www/Courses/CS180/hdparm-help.html) tells us '0' and '1' are possible values. I'm assuming it defaulted to '0' to 'get' a value instead of setting one. Am I correct? If so, how come the command failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command can either get or set the flag. When used without a parameter, it gets the flag, which you can see in the error message (`HDIO_GET_NOWERR`). So you haven’t changed anything.

The error message indicates that the device doesn’t support that particular flag anyway (either the driver, or the disk).